# Saw filter impedance matching procedure

Tags: filter, impedance-matching, sub-ghz

I need to verify (and possibly re-match) the impedance of the saw filter (in photo) to 50ohm. I have not ever matched a filter before (but have matched antennas) and am looking for advice on what procedure to use..

[image]

Comment: Start by reading and linking the data sheet for the filter.